# Sum up counts in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have directors who have directed films. These films have genres and some actors starring. I want to find the films by a directed sorted by the sum of (no of genres of the film, no of actors starring in the film).

```
MATCH(n) -- (f:Film)
WHERE n.name = "Steven Spielberg"
MATCH (f) - [r] -> (g:Genre)
OPTIONAL MATCH (f) - [r2] -> (s:Starring)
WITH n, f, count(r) as gc, count(r2) as sc
RETURN n, f, gc, sc
ORDER BY gc DESC
```

This works but now I want to sum `gc` and `sc` and order films by the result. How does one do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just add the sum you want in your `RETURN` statement and then order results by it:

```
MATCH(n) -- (f:Film)
WHERE n.name = "Steven Spielberg"
MATCH (f) - [r] -> (g:Genre)
OPTIONAL MATCH (f) - [r2] -> (s:Starring)
WITH n, f, count(r) as gc, count(r2) as sc
RETURN n, f, gc, sc, gc+sc AS S
ORDER BY S DESC
```

Comment: Careful with the cardinality! If there is more than one :Genre, and more than one :Starring, your count will include duplicates, and will not be accurate. Either get the related count immediately after you match to it (best), or use count with distinct values (like `count(distinct r)`).